# Formatting output in java assistance

Tags: java, output

Was wondering if anyone can further guide me as far as using width specifiers to making my output look like this using the static string format method ONLY.

ID:               1122

Created:          03/05/14

Owner:            Sam Williams

Opening Balance:  $14600.0

Annual Rate:      4.5

Withdraw:         5400.0

Current Balance:  $14600.0

Currently, my output is this (using tabs and new lines)

ID:      1122

Created:          03/05/14

Owner:            Sam Williams

Opening Balance:  $14600.0

Annual Rate: 4.5

Withdraw: 5400.0

Current Balance: $ 14600.0

JAVA CODE CURRENTLY IS:

```
System.out.println("ID:\t\t " + a.getId());
System.out.println("Created:\t" + String.format("%tD", a.getDateCreated()));
System.out.println("Owner:\t\t" + "" + a.getOwner() +
"\nOpening Balance: $" + a.getBalance() + "\nAnnual Rate:\t" + a.getAnnualRate() +"\nWithdraw:\t" + withDrawal +"\nCurrent Balance:\t" + " $ " + String.format("%.2f", a.getBalance()));
```

Comment: I'm confused.  Those two look very similar.  Only difference I see is two lines are in one (in first example).

Comment: Yes, it looks same to me also. And tab is normally a sequence of 4 spaces. Output does not like one.

Comment: For some reason the stack overflow editor isnt displaying what im trying to say. But im trying to make the output look "pretty" so to speak. Id like it to say all variables on left side and an even amount of spaces after, output the values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `format` method in java. It looks something like:

`System.out.format("The Name is of %d is %f.%n", i, r);`

[format method](http://web.cerritos.edu/jwilson/SitePages/java_language_resources/Java_printf_method_quick_reference.pdf)

Edited: The general syntax is: `%[flags][width][.precision][argsize]typechar`

And it will work with all the datatypes. It is an analogy of format specifier in C.

Comment: @Kunal.. If you think my answer is helpful. Please do a upvote.

Comment: @AmitShakya there you go

Answer (score 0):

You'd better learn the basic usage of String formatting in Java like decimal, float, string, date and time .

For example you can do like this with your first line:

```
System.out.println(String.format("ID:%12d" , a.getId()));
```

Here 12 is the max length if id , if your  length(id) < 12 then some space will be insert on left .

Comment: Ok. What if i wanted to format all these variables?

Comment: What is the cleanest and most basic way to do so?

Comment: You can check my edited answer. And try to implement with number first. Moreover formatting is individual thing. Format method is the cleanest way of formatting in Java.